# Django AttributeError: Importing form class

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm building a tool which has it's logic written in a separate file *tools.py*. I created a form which is suppose to pass user input to the variable in my *tools.py* file. I tried importing the forms class into my *tools.py* and assigned them to my variables but it has been showing this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'ToolsForm' has no attribute 'sender_input'
```

meanwhile these are my *forms.py* and *tools.py* file:

**Forms.py:**

```
from django import forms

class ToolsForm(forms.Form):
        sender_input = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs= 
                                        {'placeholder': 'Enter your mail account here:'}))
```

**Tools.py:**

```
from tools.forms import ToolsForm

formDetails = ToolsForm

sender_input = formDetails.sender_input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. Here is my working code.

**Tools.py**

```
from tools.forms import ToolsForm

formDetails = ToolsForm

sender_input = formDetails.declared_fields['sender_input']
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the same directory, try

```
from .forms import ToolsForm
```

The form field value might throw an error as well, the following could work.

```
sender_input = formDetails['sender_input'].value()
```